# How to "push_back" in Processing

Tags: arrays, vector, append, processing, push-back

I am trying to create Space Invaders with Processing, and I am currently working on making the shooting mechanic. I have set up where when you press T, I will make a new variable called newBullet based off the class Bullets. I will say that it is moving up and is spawned, I then want to add this newBullet to an array called bulletsArray which is an array of the class Bullets. I have worked with arrays in c++ before and you can just call a push_Back function. It might be because in c++  I call this with vectors but I can't figure out how to make a vector in processing. I found a function called append and called it like this:`bulletsArray = append(BulletsArray[], newBullet);`
but this doesn't work and gives me these errors:[image: errors]
I don't know what this is complaining about and would really appreciate help. The website I am looking at is [processing website on append()](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html).
Here is my code: [my github code](https://github.com/BobbyJoe2/SpaceInvaders/blob/3e8d793e2f7aa8b9489535b81d38916e89e21f87/Space_Invaders/Space_Invaders.pde)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a c++ Vector, you will have an easier time working with an ArrayList than a normal array.

To do this, you'll have to declare your arraylist like you did with your current array, but initialize it in the `Setup()` function.

```
//Global declaration
ArrayList<Bullets> bullets;

//in the Setup() function
ArrayList<Bullets> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullets>();
```

ArrayLists are dynamic and easy to use, and they have a bunch of little tools which may help you later on. In your case, you'll want to add bullets and remove some:

```
bullets.Add(New Bullets(....))
bullets.Remove(i)
```

Have fun!